# Javascript : How to get root directory from a path

Tags: javascript, regex, filepath

I have a file path for eg. `"/abc/xyz/123/file.txt"`. How can I get the root directory ie."abc" from this path. I tried the following code:

```
var path = "/abc/xyz/123/file.txt";
var rootDir = path.split("/")[1];
```

This works for the above example. But the path can also be in below formats:

```
1. "abc/xyz/123/file.txt"
2. "\abc\xyz\123\file.txt"(backslash instead of forward slash path separator)
```

How to do this covering all the scenarios? Can this be done using `regex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this `match(/[^/\\]+/)`

```js
var reg = /[^/\\]+/

console.log( "abc/xyz/123/file.txt".match(reg) )
console.log( "/abc/xyz/123/file.txt".match(reg) )
console.log( "\\abc\\xyz\\123\\file.txt".match(reg) )
```

Comment: Is it a valid scenario to have path separator as something other than "/"  on different OS?

Comment: nah, don't think so... would be supper weird otherwise